# Redirect the form result on the same form page in the form of table using Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring and I have been given a task to do. I have created a simple registration form for employee using spring mvc and its result is getting displayed on another jsp page but I want the result to be displayed on the same jsp page where I have filled the form and the result should be in tabular form too.

I tried forward and redirect options also but I am not getting to the result.

Here are my files:

EmployeeFormController.java

```
public class EmployeeFormController extends SimpleFormController {
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)
throws ServletException {
Employee employee = (Employee) command;  

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("usersuccess");
modelAndView.addObject("employee", employee);
return modelAndView;  
}  

}
```

user.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="/spring"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Employee Personal Details</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <center> <h3>Employee Personal Details</h3>
   <br/>
   <form:form commandName="user" method="POST" name="user">
   <table border="0">
   <tr>
   <td>Name:</td>
   <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
   <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="name"/></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Email ID:</td>
   <td><form:input path="emailid"/></td>
   <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="emailid"/></font></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Date of birth:</td>
 <td><form:input path="dob"/></td>
<td><font color="red"><form:errors path="dob"/></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Qualification:</td>
<td><form:input path="qualification"/></td>
<td><font color="red"><form:errors path="qualification"/></font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number:</td>
<td><form:input path="contact"/></td>
<td><font color="red"><form:errors path="contact"/></font></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><form:input path="address"/></td>
<td><font color="red"><form:errors path="address"/></font></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</center> 
</body>
</html>
```

usersuccess.jsp

```
<table border = 2>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="5">Employee Information</font></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><core:out value="${employee.name}"/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email ID:</td>
<td><core:out value="${employee.emailid}"/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date Of Birth:</td>
<td><core:out value="${employee.dob}"/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Qualification:</td>
<td><core:out value="${employee.qualification}"/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number:</td>
<td><core:out value="${employee.contact}"/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><core:out value="${employee.address}"/></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="userController" class="com.web.EmployeeFormController">
<property name="sessionForm"><value>false</value></property>
<property name="commandName"><value>user</value></property>
<property name="commandClass"><value>com.web.Employee</value></property>
<property name="formView"><value>user</value></property>
<property name="successView"><value>usersuccess</value></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just do

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user");
```

instead of

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("usersuccess");
```

If you want to display the answer in the same page. Please note that if you want to display in tabular form you will have to copy the code from usersuccess.jsp  to user.jsp and modify your code accordingly

Comment: I have tried this thing many times but it is giving some binding error every time I am doing.. If you want I will share the exact error also

Comment: Yes .. Please share the exact error that you are getting. Please provide detailed logs.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC by itself is a "round-trip" deal, meaning you submit a request (form post, url, etc), Spring MVC routes the request and generates a response, which the browser interprets as a page load.  What you are asking for is typically referred to as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), and has very little to do with Spring MVC directly.

This is a 50000ft view on the process.  On your form JSP, you would have some JavaScript that is called when the user "submits" the form.  For instance, you could have an input of type button with a jQuery event handler.  From there, you would gather up the form values and submit them using an AJAX call.  Once the response comes back, you would then parse the returned data and manipulate the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) on the page, again using JavaScript.

There are probably millions of examples on how to do this on the web using a multitude of different techniques.  I personally perfer [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as my JavaScript library, and I use its [ajax capabilities](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) almost extensively.  This is not the only way to do it, though.

Comment: Hii thanks for the answer..actually I know it can be easily done through ajax but I was told to do it through spring so I was trying to do without using ajax..that I was not able to find..

Comment: If your hands are tied, then your only option is to post and wait for the page to reload.